# 2GB limit on file size when using fwrite in C?

Tags: c, filesystems, fwrite, fat32

I have a short C program that writes into a file until there is no more space on disk:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char c[] = "abcdefghij";
  size_t rez;
  FILE *f = fopen("filldisk.dat", "wb");
  while (1) {
    rez = fwrite(c, 1, sizeof(c), f);
    if (!rez) break;
  }
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

When I run the program (in Linux), it stops when the file reaches 2GB.

Is there an internal limitation, due to the FILE structure, or something?

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like the positive 1/2 of a 32-bit integer.

Comment: Which file system is your hard drive formatted as?

Comment: Linux says "vfat", which is FAT32 I think. It is a 4GB flash drive, which is initially (almost) empty.

Comment: vfat (FAT32) has a limit of 2GB per file anyways, it doesn't matter what you use to code it.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314463 XP has a FAT filesize limit of 4GB-1B.  I thought Linux's vfat would limit at 2GB but reading the source code now I think I was wrong.

Comment: My rule of thumb for portable access to files on removable media is to limit the file to just under 2GB, which is FAT16's limit because the documentation is vague about whether the size entry is unsigned or signed. Unfortunately, there are a fair number of incorrect apps out there.

Comment: I think VFAT filesize limit is 2Gb - I believe the confusion is that file access is 4GB, but that's to allow for +/- 2GB access in either seek direction

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On a 32 bits system (i.e. the OS is 32 bits), by default, fopen and co are limited to 32 bits size/offset/etc... You need to enable the large file support, or use the *64 bits option:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html#index-fopen64-931

Then your fs needs to support this, but except fat and other primitive fs, all of them support creating files > 2 gb.

Answer (score 12):

> it stops when the file reaches 2GB.
>
> Is there an internal limitation, due
>   to the FILE structure, or something?

This is due to the libc (the standard C library), which by default on a x86 (IA-32) Linux system is 32-bit functions provided by glibc (GNU's C Library). So by default the [file stream size](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html#Opening-Streams) is based upon 32-bits -- 2^(32-1).

For using [Large File Support](http://www.suse.de/~aj/linux_lfs.html), see the web page.

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS  64
/* or more commonly add -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 to CFLAGS */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char c[] = "abcdefghij";
  size_t rez;
  FILE *f = fopen("filldisk.dat", "wb");
  while (1) {
    rez = fwrite(c, 1, sizeof(c), f);
    if ( rez < sizeof(c) ) { break; }
  }
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

Note: Most systems expect fopen (and off_t) to be based on 2^31 file size limit. Replacing them with `off64_t` and `fopen64` makes this explicit, <s>and depending on usage might be best way to go.</s> but is not recommended in general as they are non-standard.

Comment: Never use the *64 functions. Always compile all programs with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`.

Comment: Mostly agreed, as the *64 functions are not portable, and not well-defined in any standards, but they do make the requirement explicit which may be good in some limited cases.