# Is fopen() limited by the filesystem?

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I wrote a program to generate large .SQL files for quickly populating very large databases.  I scripted it in PHP.  When I started coding I was using **fopen()** and **fwrite()**.  When files got too large the program would return control to the shell and the file would be incomplete.

Unfortunately I'm not sure exactly how large is 'too large'. I think it may have been around 4GB.

To solve this problem I had the file **echo** to stdout.  I redirected it when I called the program like so:

```
[root@localhost]$ php generatesql.php > myfile.sql
```

Which worked like a charm. My output file ended up being about 10GB.

My question, then, is: Are **fopen()** and **fwrite()** limited by the file system in terms of how large a file they are capable of generating?  If so; is this a limitation of PHP?  Does this happen in other languages as well?

Comment: Show some code...  Likely it's because you're on a 32 bit operating system, and you're overflowing the int limit on the file position (but that's just speculation unless you called either `ftell` or `fseek`)...

Comment: Will show some code as soon as I get home from the office.

Comment: @ircmaxell: fseek() was called at the very end of execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's probably occuring is the underlying PHP build is 32bit and can't handle file pointers >4GB - see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730709/2gb-limit-on-file-size-when-using-fwrite-in-c).

Your underlying OS is obviously capable of storing large files, which why you're able to redirect stdout to a large file.

Incidentally, an SQL file is likely to be highly compressible, so you might like to consider using the [gzip fopen wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php) to compress the file as you write it.

```
$file = 'compress.zlib:///path/to/my/file.sql.gz';
$f = fopen($file, 'wb');

    //just write as normal...
    fwrite($f, 'CREATE TABLE foo (....)');

fclose($f);
```

Your dump will be a fraction of the original size, and you can restore it simply piping the output from [zcat](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_zcat.htm) into an SQL client, e.g. for mysql

```
zcat /path/to/my/file.sql.gz | mysql mydatabase
```

Comment: I'm on 32-bit and I can't generate files > 2GiB. http://stackoverflow.com/q/19438203/89771

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. Its not *fopen()* or *fwrite()* which are limited directly, its the files, which cannot exceed some dimensions depending on the filesystem. Have a look at [Comparison of filesystems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) on Wikipedia.

Comment: But if that's the case, how come output redirection worked in generating a ~10 GB file for the OP?

Comment: Why not? The *f*()* ("File"-Functions) usually work on streams. So if you call *fwrite()* it buffers only up to (I assume) 4kB, before writes the output directly to the open stream (the return value of *fopen()*). Now your script runs and runs and fills the file, but at some point the filesystems blocks any further data, because of maximum file size. In fact, I dont know, if this really happens to you, because 10GB is a odd value. Anyway: Try to split it in multiple files (of lets say <4GB). You dont know exactly on FS the files get saved later.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your script is taking too long to execute and has timed out?

Alternatively, is it possible that you're reaching your memory limits within the script?

Comment: it's executing with php-cli; definitely not a timeout issue.  if the memory limit was reached there would have been an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can write more than 2GB of data in a **stream**, not in a **file** (as the fseek internal pointer of the file is exceeding PHP limits, and streams are not usually seekable)

`<?
$target = fopen('test.tar', 'w');  //this is a file, limited by php to 2GB
$body = str_repeat("===", 1024 * 1024);
while(true)
  fwrite($target, $test);`

`<?
$target = popen('cat > test.tar', 'w'); //this is a stream, no limitation here
$body = str_repeat("===", 1024 * 1024);
while(true)
  fwrite($target, $test);`