# File size can't exceed 2 Go

Tags: linux

I am doing Monte Carlo simulations. I am trying to direct the results of my program into a Huge file using fprintf to avoid tabs because it necessitate much memory size.

The problem is that, when the data size on file achieve 2Go, the program can't write on it anymore. I did some research in this and other sites but I didn't get a helpful response to my problem.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with file type ext4 and the partition size is 88 Go. I am not good at computer sciences and I don't know even what means ext but I saw that this type of file can support individual files with 16 Go at least.

So can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [2GB limit on file size when using fwrite in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730709/2gb-limit-on-file-size-when-using-fwrite-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

The maximal file size limit for a 32 bit is 2^31 (2 GiB), but using the LFS interface on filesystems that support LFS applications can handle files as large as 263 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer it was so helpful. I changed fopen with fopen64 and i used -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 when compiling, and all got fine :)