# Storing a huge array in a file, row by row, results in a damaged file

Tags: c, arrays, file, fwrite, fread

I have an input array A stored in the memory, which is used to produce another array, much bigger B. However, since B is a huge array, I don't really want to store it in the memory, but to save it locally into a file (using `fwrite`). For this, I calculate every iteration the `i`<sup>th</sup> row and append it to the output file. That way, I only need to store one row at a time in the memory, and eventually, an output file is created, with all the data I needed.

The output file seems to be in proper size, considering the number of items it consists of. Nevertheless, when I try to read back fragments from the output file using `fread`, (for instance, retrieve the first 2000 items), only the first 23 items are retrieved.

This is the primary function to create the output file:

```
void exportCovMatrix(char *outputString, double *inputStdMatrix, int colDim, int rowDim) {
    double *covRow = calloc(rowDim, sizeof(double));
    int i, j, n;
    FILE *output;
    fclose(fopen(outputString, "w"));
    output = fopen(outputString, "a");
    assert(covRow != NULL);
    assert(output != NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < rowDim; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < rowDim; j++)
            covRow[j] = dotProduct(&inputStdMatrix[i * colDim], &inputStdMatrix[j * colDim], colDim);
        n = fwrite(covRow, sizeof(double), rowDim, output);
        assert(n == rowDim);
    }
    fclose(output);
    free(covRow);
}
```

This is another function, that reads the given output file:

```
double *calculateNextB(char* inputString, double* row, int dim){
    FILE* input = fopen(inputString, "r");
    int i, j;
    assert(input != NULL);
    for(i = 0; i <= dim; i++){
        j = fread(row, sizeof(double), dim, input);
        printf("%d items were read.\n", j);
    }
    ...
}
```

I'd appreciate any help in solving this issue. Thanks!

Comment: `fclose(fopen(outputString, "w"));` Suspicious line. What does it do?

Comment: It clears the file contents before we write anything new to the file. Originally, this line wasn't there, and I opened the file in write mode instead of append mode. In both ways I ended up with same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You open the file respectively with

```
fclose(fopen(outputString, "w"));
```

and

```
FILE* input = fopen(inputString, "r");
```

But as explained for example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/)

> In order to open a file as a binary file a "b" character has to be included in the mode string.

(I know it is a C++ source, but in some system it is true, though it's not in many POSIX systems, as explained in https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen )

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume the file is really big.

On a 32 bits system, the stream related functions (fopen, fwrite, etc.) are limited to 2GiB. Over this size, the effection of the functions is not defined.

Please refer to this page.

```
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html#index-fopen64-931
```

Also refer to this question.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730709/2gb-limit-on-file-size-when-using-fwrite-in-c
```

Answer (score 1):

regarding this (slightly modified) proposed code:

1. which properly checks for errors
2. avoids the use of `assert()` in (possibly) production code
3. calculates each line of data, then writes that line to the file.
4. sets the file size back to 0 length each time this function is called.
5. properly indicates the file is a 'binary' file rather than a 'text' file.
6. does not compile due to 'nothing' for function: `dotproduct()`
7. does not know the length of each row in `inputStdMatrix[ rowDim ][ colDim ]`
8. and shouldn't this parameter: `double *inputStdMatrix` be written as: `double inputStdMatrix[][ colDim ]` with the parameters `rowDim` and `colDim` be before this parameter
9. properly limits the 'scope' of the local variables

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void exportCovMatrix(char *outputString, size_t colDim, size_t rowDim, double inputStdMatrix[][ colDim ], ) 
{
    double *covRow = calloc(rowDim, sizeof(double));
    if( ! covRow )
    {
        perror( "calloc for row of data failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    FILE *output;
    output = fopen(outputString, "wb");
    if( ! output )
    {
        perror( "fopen for write binary file failed" );
        free( covRow );  // cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // assert(covRow != NULL);
    // assert(output != NULL);

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rowDim; i++) 
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < rowDim; j++)
        {
            covRow[j] = dotProduct(&inputStdMatrix[i * colDim],
                                   &inputStdMatrix[j * colDim], 
                                    colDim);
        }

        size_t n = fwrite(covRow, sizeof(double), rowDim, output);
        // assert(n == rowDim);
        if( n != rowDim )
        {
            // handle error of short write
        }
    }

    fclose(output);
    free(covRow);
}
```

which only writes `rowDim` lines to the file.

Then, if it is called again, it erases what was in the file.  probably not what you want.